# How to write czech diacritics on en_US keyboard

Tags: ubuntu, keyboard-layout, diacritics

Is it possible to write some of the czech specific symbols using english (en_US default) keyboard?

```
ě š č ř ž á í é
```

I need to be able to write the `ˇ` and `'` symbols. Right now I am switching english/czech keyboards, but that's not the way to go, as the czech keyboard has different keymaps for `? !` etc.

I am working on ubuntu.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, and it is quite easy. This is for Ubuntu 12.04LTS but should work similarly on other systems.

Step 1. Designate a keyboard key as the compose key. For example.

Set “System Settings … -> Keyboard Layout -> Options… -> Compose Key Position to Right Alt” as compose key to type in diacritics.

Step 2. Enter special characters as needed:

See https://help.ubuntu.com/12.04/ubuntu-help/tips-specialchars.html#compose

For instance, from the link mentioned above:

Press compose then ' then a letter to place an acute accent over that letter, such as é.

Press compose then ` (back tick) then a letter to place a grave accent over that letter, such as è.

Press compose then " then a letter to place an umlaut over that letter, such as ë.

Press compose then - then a letter to place a macron over that letter, such as ē.

Perhaps the tricky one which is not mentioned on the site, which is required to

in order to write proper Czech, is ů. To type this letter, the combination is

Compose Key + * + u.

For capital letters, for instance Š, you can type Compose, then ", then SHIFT+S.

This covers the complete set of required characters for Czech language input

using a plain ASCII keyboard.

Regards.

Answer (score 0):

I know the answer is a bit late, but it might help others.

I program with English (US) layout, but sometimes I need to write something in Czech. In Windows, I got used to Czech Programmer keyboard layout (English layout with Czech special symbols available with AltGr at the same place). Ubuntu has almost the same layout (called "Czech (coder)"), but it is a bit hidden.

In order to enable it, go to `/usr/share/X11/xkb/rules`. Add line

```
  coder       cz: Czech (coder)
```

to `evdev.lst` file next to other variants. Similarly, add

```
<variant>
  <configItem>
    <name>coder</name>
    <description>Czech (coder)</description>
  </configItem>
</variant>
```

to `evdev.xml` right next to other variants (has to be in Czech keyboard variant list). Keyboard layout variant should be now listed in Settings.